# How to pass argument to a custom widget in DOJO?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am creating some custom widgets in DOJO.
I need to be able to overwrite some properties on the widget at object initialization, example: new `_labelWebpart('my value here');`

Any idea how to do it?

```
 var widget2 = new _labelWebpart('my value here');


   define([
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dijit/_WidgetBase",
        "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dojo/text!./templates/label.html",
        "dojo/dom-style",
        "dojo/_base/fx",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/mouse",
        "require"
    ], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template, domStyle, baseFx, lang, on, mouse, require) {
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
            label: "Default text for label", // THIS VALUE SHOULD BE OVERWRITTEN WHEN PASSING ARGUMENT IN THE COSTRUCTOR
            templateString: template,
            baseClass: "Label",
              postCreate: function () {
                var domNode = this.domNode;
                  this.own(
                );
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend looking into a constructor property:

```
   return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        label: "Default text for label",
        templateString: template,

        // other stuff of your declare here

        constructor: function(override_arguments_here) {
           // your init code here to override the label from your arguments
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is the first point of execution in the file. The declare skeleton should be as follows:

```js
    return declare("fileNameIfHTMLIsDifferent", [.....], {
  templateString: _templateString
  ....
  , constructor: function(args) {
   declare.safeMixin(this, args);
   ....
  }
  , postCreate: function() {
   this.inherited(arguments);
      ....
  },
    startup: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
    }
 });
```